# how to overcome 'plot' and 'fill' function restrictions

Tags: pine-script

I am a professional C programmer and now I make my first steps in Pinescript :-)
so I wrote one simple and working script:

```
study("test - 1")

var float sum = 0
var float prev_sum = 0
var float per = 0
prev_sum := 0
sum := 0
per := 0

f_print( _text, _color, _y ) =>
    var _label = label.new( x=bar_index-4, y=1, text = _text, xloc = xloc.bar_index, yloc = yloc.price, color = color(na), style = label.style_none, textcolor = _color, size = size.small, textalign = text.align_right )
    label.set_xy( _label, bar_index -20, _y +5 )
    label.set_text( _label, _text )

p0 = plot( 0, title="X axle", color = color.black )

t1 = "CRYPTOCAP:BTC.D"
per := security( t1, timeframe.period, ohlc4 )
sum := sum + per
p1 = plot( sum, title=t1, color = color.red )
fill( p0, p1, color.red )

f_print( "BTC.D  " + tostring( round( per, 3 ) ), color.red, prev_sum )
prev_sum := sum

t2 = "CRYPTOCAP:ETH.D"
per := security( t2, timeframe.period, ohlc4 )
sum := sum + per
p2 = plot( sum, title=t2, color = color.blue )
fill( p1, p2, color.blue )

f_print( "ETH.D  " + tostring( round( per, 3 ) ), color.blue, prev_sum )
```

and it is working just fine, 
the problem is that I wish to add another dozen of tickers for plotting, 
so I tried to optimize my code and to make a function for the repeating part:

```
study( "test - 2" )

var float sum = 0
sum := 0

f_print( _text, _color, _y ) =>
    var _label = label.new( x=bar_index, y=1, text=_text, xloc=xloc.bar_index, yloc=yloc.price, color=color(na), style=label.style_none, textcolor=_color, size=size.small, textalign=text.align_right )
    label.set_xy( _label, bar_index -20, _y +5 )
    label.set_text( _label, _text )


plot_domin( _ticker, _sum, _pl, _color ) =>
    per = security( _ticker, timeframe.period, ohlc4 )
    loc_sum = _sum + per
    pl_ret = plot( loc_sum, title=_ticker, color = _color )
    fill( _pl, pl_ret, color.red )
    f_print( _ticker + " " + tostring( round( per, 3 ) ), _color, _sum )
    [ loc_sum, pl_ret ]


p0 = plot( 0, title="X axle", color = color.black )
[ sum, p1 ] = plot_domin( "CRYPTOCAP:BTC.D", sum, p0, color.red  )
[ sum, p2 ] = plot_domin( "CRYPTOCAP:ETH.D", sum, p1, color.blue  )
```

but here I hit two restrictions:

```
line 23: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope.;
line 24: Cannot call 'fill' with arguments (<plot_domin_arg2_type>, plot, const color); available overloads: fill(hline, hline, series[color], input integer, const string, const bool, const bool, string) => void; fill(plot, plot, series[color], input integer, const string, const bool, input integer, const bool, string) => void;
```

and the most strange is that it is complaining that

```
line 31: 'sum' is already defined.
```

so I even can not use a one and the same variable for 'sum' and I have to use 'sum1', 'sum2', ...

Any idea, how to avoid the repeating part of code and 
to avoid the multiplication of usage of different variables on every return value from a function?

thank you in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
//@version=4
study("")

var string sym01 = "CRYPTOCAP:BTC.D"
var string sym02 = "CRYPTOCAP:ETH.D"

var color  c_sym01 = color.red
var color  c_sym02 = color.blue

var float sum = 0.

f_print( _text, _color, _y, _line ) =>
    var _label = label.new( bar_index, na, "", color = color(na), style = label.style_label_lower_left, textcolor = _color, size = size.small, textalign = text.align_right )
    if barstate.islast
        label.set_xy( _label, bar_index, _y)
        label.set_text( _label, _text)
        label.set_textcolor( _label, _color )

f_domin( _ticker, _color, _y, _line) =>
    // Use `nz()` to account for cases where there is no data on the tickers.
    _return = nz(security( _ticker, timeframe.period, ohlc4 ))
    // Generate label text.
    _newLines = array.join(array.new_string(max(0, _line - 1), "\n"))
    _text = _ticker + tostring( _return, "  #.000" ) + _newLines
    // Display label.
    f_print(_text, _color, _y, _line)
    _return

p_00 = plot( 0, title="X axle", color = color.black )

sum += f_domin(sym01, c_sym01, sum[1], 1)
p_01 = plot( sum, sym01, c_sym01 )

sum += f_domin(sym02, c_sym02, sum[1], 2)
p_02 = plot( sum, sym02, c_sym02 )

fill( p_00, p_01, c_sym01 )
fill( p_00, p_02, c_sym02 )
```

Note that:

- We use `var` to initialize strings and colors on the first bar of the dataset only.
- We need to keep the `plot()` and `fill()` calls out of functions because they are not allowed there. We can, however, create the labels from within `f_domin()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot PineCoders-LucF :-)<br>
That helped me a lot and saved me a lot of time  :-)<br>
I have two more question:

Comment: 1. I wish the "plots" to work in the "resolution" selected by the chart, but independent from the chart "resolution", I wish to made some calculation based on 30m resolution for on the last 48 30m bars and to include that information in f_print() function - actually I need to call f_print() only on the last bar<br>

Comment: 2. how to efficiently get the min/max value for example for "CRYPTOCAP:ETH.D"
 for the visible part on the screen chart, but PRIOR TO START the first plot for the first bar<br>

Comment: 1. See our MTF Selection Framework for ways to provide choices of timeframes for `security()` calls: https://www.tradingview.com/script/90mqACUV-MTF-Selection-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/

Comment: 2. Pine scripts have no visibility on how many bars are currently displayed on the chart.

Comment: "MTF Selection Framework" - honestly I do not understand completely what is the purpose of that and how to use it :-)
I found out that, by putting 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on indexes in 
   <pre>security( _tickerid, "30", low[ 3 ]  )<code>
that do the thing that I need, but when I try to call the security via 'for' loop:

Comment: get_val( _idx ) =>
    security( syminfo.tickerid, "30", low[ _idx ]  )
<br>
if barstate.islast <br>
    for i = 1 to 10 <br>
        curr_val = get_val( i ) <br>
//        curr_val = low[i] <br>
        label2 = label.new( bar_index-i, low[i]-300, text = tostring( curr_val, "0" ), style = label.style_label_center, color = color.green, size = size.small) <br>

Comment: does not work, for unknown reason it is not taking properly the value of 'i' <br> I am apology, but I do not know how to preserve the formatting on the previous comment

Comment: Code is unreadable in comments here. Ask another question if this one was answered and you have another question, please. You can't use the `security()` or its results in a `for` loop like that. You can send a function up with `security()` which itself contains a `for` loop, if you need to execute that loop in the HTF context of `security()`.

Comment: thank you @PineCoders-LucF for the help!
I created a new question and I definitely consider that question as answered!!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67611315/pinescript-passing-for-loop-index-to-a-function-does-not-work