# PineScript: passing 'for loop" index to a function does not work

Tags: pine-script

In order to check security() functionality I wrote that very simple code:

```
get_val( _idx ) => 
    security( syminfo.tickerid, "30", low[ _idx ] ) 

if barstate.islast
    for i = 1 to 10 
        curr_val = get_val( i ) 
        // curr_val = low[i] 
        label2 = label.new( bar_index-i, low[i]-300, text = tostring( curr_val, "0" ), 
             style = label.style_label_center, color = color.green, size = size.small)
```

and I expect, that it will correctly print the 'low' value on each candle,
but for unknown reason it does not correctly pass the values of 'i'
to get_val() function.

Q1. what is the problematic in 'i' when it is 'for loop' index

Q2. my target is when I come to the last candle in the chart,
to get high/low/ohlc4 value for specific ticker, for the last 9 30min periods,
and based on that to calculate average difference in the price for those 9 periods
-- what is the correct/working/effective approach to do this via security(), because I wish to calculate it for several different tickers in one chart.

I read the info in https://www.tradingview.com/script/90mqACUV-MTF-Selection-Framework-PineCoders-FAQ/ , https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html and https://www.tradingview.com/script/00jFIl5w-security-revisited-PineCoders/ , but I still can not find a working solution

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `security()` like that, from inside a loop. Whatever you need to accomplish in `security()`'s HTF context has to be done from within a function sent to it. This shows a few examples.

Not sure if `f_htf5()` does what you had in mind, but it will give you an idea. Handling repainting/no-repainting is trickier when the function sent to `security()` is returning a tuple:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
var string ON  = "On"
var string OFF = "Off"
bool i_repaint = input(OFF, "Repaint", options = [ON, OFF]) == ON

f_htf1(_src, _p) =>
    // #1 Avg of last `_p` values of `_src`
    float _return = sma(_src, _p)
    
f_htf2(_src, _p) =>
    // #2 Sum of last `_p` values of `_src`
    float _return = sum(_src, _p)
    
f_htf3(_src, _p) =>
    // #3 Last value is lower than all `_p` past values
    int _return = _src < lowest(_src, _p)[1] ? 1 : 0
    
f_htf4(_src, _p) =>
    // #4 Find the closest value to `_src` in `_p` past values
    float _delta = 10e15
    float _closestVal = na
    for _i = 1 to _p
        float _diff = abs(_src - _src[_i])
        if _diff < _delta
            _delta := _diff
            _closestVal := _src[_i]
    float _return = _closestVal

f_htf5(_p, _offset) =>
    // #4 Return the avg of past `_p` `high`, `low`, `ohlc4` values
    float _hi = sma(high, _p)
    float _lo = sma(low, _p)
    float _ohlc4 = sma(ohlc4, _p)
    [_hi[_offset], _lo[_offset], _ohlc4[_offset]]

// Function from: https://www.tradingview.com/script/00jFIl5w-security-revisited-PineCoders/
f_security(_sym, _res, _src, _rep) => security(_sym, _res, _src[not _rep and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_rep or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

// For functions returning one value (f_htf1 - f_htf4), execute the function in `security()`'s HTF context.
htfValue = f_security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", f_htf3(low, 10), i_repaint)

// For functions returning a tuple.
int ofst1 = not i_repaint and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0
int ofst2 = i_repaint or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1
[hi01_, lo01_, ohlc01_] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", f_htf5(9, ofst1))
float hi01   = hi01_[ofst2]
float lo01   = lo01_[ofst2]
float ohlc01 = ohlc01_[ofst2]

plot(hi01, "hi01", color.fuchsia)
plot(lo01, "lo01", color.aqua)
plot(ohlc01, "ohlc01", color.green)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @PineCoders-LucF, I will need some time to sit and to study it,
it is definitely much more clear for me how to use  f_security()!